# When induction proofs need a choice function

Tags: logic, induction, axiom-of-choice

Reading the comment to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072344/separable-hahn-banach-and-the-axiom-of-choice) the user makes the argument that one can pick a dense subset of a separable vector spaces without relying the axiom of countable choices. Since the comment got a lot of up votes, I guess it's correct, but to me this seems very strange. My rule of thumb was/is the following: We can get by without a choice function if

- There is a canonical choice at each iteration.
- The proof doesn't actually require the iteration process to terminate.

None of these seem to be satisfied in the present case, unless there is a canonical choice for the dense subset, or the set is dense at some finite iteration, so my question is:

When can I tell if an induction arguments relies on the existence of a countable choice function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that a canonical choice function is needed for recursive constructions.

However, if you have an underlying set which is countable—or generally can be well-ordered—then there *is* a canonical choice function given by enumerating the set, and at each step choosing the element with the least index in the enumeration which "fits".

In those cases, you only need to prove that the recursive construction can actually proceed from $n$ steps to $n+1$ steps. Just like you would in "the usual case where choice is assumed".

Note that to choose *one* element from a family which is assumed to be non-empty, no choice is needed. So if you assume that a set is countable, for example, you don't need the axiom of choice to enumerate it. You already *assume* that an enumeration exists.

---

Also, let me point out this minor issue that "countable choice" only means that you can make a choice *once* from a countable family of sets. What you want for recursive definitions and/or inductive proofs, is *Dependent Choice*, which allows you to make a countable sequence of choices, where each choice might depend on the previous ones you made. Just like in a recursive definition.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623210/hahn-banach-theorem-for-separable-spaces-without-zorns-lemma) which related to this post. Via recursive construction, we have _one_ $f_n$ defined each step, and can be defined for _every_ $n$. But in the bullet point 4, to claim a function $g$ is defined for infinite dimensional space, with $g=\cup^\infty_{n=1}f_n$, don't I need _all_ $f_n$ at disposal _simultaneously_? For that, is ordinary 'induction' suffice or the fact that canonical choice exists for all closed intervals has played a role?

Comment: @lychtalent: Since we can *canonically* and *uniformly* define the $f_n$'s, then we actually get the sequence of *all* the $f_n$'s simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just to check if I get it, defining $f_n$'s _cannonically_ and _uniformly_ as such can never be done by ordinary induction without additional property of $\mathbb{R}$, and the recursive construction is just appearing to be similar to induction, right? For example, if in the original post, $f_n$ is defined on some abstract set, not on $\mathbb{R}$, a function $g$ defined for infinite dimensional space may not exist without choice, right?

Comment: @lychtalent: No, the construction *is* recursive. It's just that since we have a canonical way of choosing "the next step", we do not need to appeal to choice to ensure that the sequence of functions is also an object. The uniformity and/or canonicity of these things is indeed a structural consequence of the real numbers, yes.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized the poor way I was questioning may have just confused myself. Your 'No' is to state construction is no ordinary induction, therefore my first part of the statement is correct, and your 'yes' in the end is to agree with my second part of the statement. Am I interpreting it correctly? (I add 'right?' in the end of my question out of habit, which clearly is no good)

Comment: @lychtalent: I said "no", because you asked if the construction "only looks like recursion, but it's not *really* recursion". That's wrong. The construction **is** by ordinary recursion.

Comment: Oh now I see. I think I got confused by [Induction-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction-recursion) and [Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). By 'induction' I actually meant the latter. Hope this time I am correct. Thanks!

Comment: I notice you treat _recursion_ as synonyms of _induction_ here, but what I had in mind the concept of _induction_ is always $P(n-1)\implies P(n)$, the technique used for proof certain property, not use for construction.

Comment: @lychtalent I thought you are constructing the sequence of functions. Not proving that all of its members have some property.

Comment: Then same term _induction_ is used in both 1) constructing something (recursion), and 2) proving some properties (mathematical induction), where it in fact means different things?

Comment: @lychtalent: This will be my last comment on the topic (and on the Hahn–Banach topic in general). The construction is by recursion, not induction. I've been a logician for my entire mathematical career and I know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 4):

Your misunderstanding seems to come from the fact that you are not *iterating* making choices -- you are not picking the elements of the countable dense subset one by one, or anything like that. By definition, "$X$ is separable" means that
$$
\{Y \in \mathcal P(X) \mid |Y| \leq \aleph_0 \land \overline{Y} = X\} \neq \emptyset.
$$
Since it is non-empty, it contains some element. Pick one element from this set -- we can call it $Y$. There is no further iteration to be done; you now have a separating subset $Y$ of $X$.